# Open file on IntelliJ from iTerm 2

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, iterm2

I have output in my iTerm that is like:

```
  File project/path/path/file.py:56:54 extra text information
```

How can I open this file in IntelliJ with a single click?

Comment: I wonder if there's an AppleScript solution to this. Running the JetBrains binary fires up a JVM, so there's quite a delay

Answer (score 45, accepted):

IntelliJ has a command line features that you can check out here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2024.1/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html

iTerm as well enable launch a command line order when we use `cmd and click` over a file path pattern.

You only have to go to iTerm Preferences, Profiles, Advanced, Semantic History

[image: iTerm configuration]

In Semantic History check "Run Comand.." and add as a command:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea  --line \2 \1
```

IntelliJ has to be in the current project. You can enforce a project:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea <project_path> --line \2 \1
```

or event use `\5` as a project path, `\5`  is a pwd in the current terminal directory.

I had better results with the first configuration.

Note: with IntelliJ Idea 2019.1 i used: `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea  --line \2 \1`

---

I move to pycharm, and I am currently using this line:

```
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm  --line \2 \1
```

**UPDATE**

Several people in the comments and other responses have suggested using `--line \2 \1` instead of `\1 --line \2`. So, I've updated this in the answer in several places.

Comment: Awesome! With eslint I had to use the following formatter to get line numbers to work https://github.com/royriojas/eslint-friendly-formatter

Comment: WebStorm 2018.3 ignores the --line param if it isn't first, so I had to use:

/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm --line \2 \1

Comment: Using Webstorm 2019.2.3 this takes about 5 seconds to detect the current instance. `open -a` is instant, but `--line lineX $file` and `$file:lineX` both ignore the line number. Do you know how to open on the file line with no delay?

Comment: I had to add quotes around the path. I think because iTerm was launching it with `/bin/sh`: `"/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea" --line \2 \1`

Comment: `/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine --line \2 \1`  works for my with RubyMine 2021.1.  Make sure you start a new iTerm session after setting the command.

Comment: You could put the 2019.1 edit on the initial response, it's been a while now

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer didn't quite work for me. I ended up using:

```
open -a "IntelliJ IDEA" \1
```

Comment: Could you get this working with a line number? I tried 

open -a "IntelliJ IDEA" \1 --args --line \2

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm the following command is working with or without line numbers, when entered into **iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Semantic History > Run Command**:

```
 [ -z \2 ] && /usr/local/bin/idea \1 || /usr/local/bin/idea --line \2 \1
```

This makes use of the fact that IntelliJ IDEA installs a command line launcher python script `idea` to `/usr/local/bin`, and requires the project in which the file resides to be open (multiple projects can be open, and it will still find the correct one.)

The command checks to see if the line number argument `\2` is blank; if it is, it will exclude the line number, otherwise it will specify it with `--line`.  `\1` is the filename including the path.

To see all the available options for `idea`:

```
/usr/local/bin/idea --help
```

Environment:

- iTerm2 3.1.7
- IntelliJ IDEA CE 2018.1.5
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: It works! thank you. Here's my usage that opens both files with and without line numbers `[ -z \2 ] && /Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/MacOS/goland \1 ||  /Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/MacOS/goland --line \2 \1`

Comment: It's working for me too, in RubyMine, with and without line numbers.  `[ -z \2 ] && /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine \1 || /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/MacOS/rubymine --line \2 \1`

Comment: It works in PyCharm on both case:
`[ -z \2 ] && /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm \1 ||  /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm --line \2 \1`

Answer (score 9):

Here is the command to open a file in WebStorm via `Command + Click` on a file path .
Go to `Settings > Profiles > Advanced > Semantic History > Run command` and input

```
/usr/local/bin/webstorm --line \2 \1
```

For the IntelliJ Idea this line should work ([documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-files-from-command-line.html)):

```
/usr/local/bin/idea --line \2 \1
```

One of the problem with those solutions is that they only work for file paths that contain a line number like `/some/path/to/file.txt:15` and do nothing when the path has no line number like `/some/path/to/file.txt`.

The most robust solution is:

```
[ -z \2 ] && /usr/local/bin/idea \1 || /usr/local/bin/idea --line \2 \1
```

Comment: Tried setting up — WebStorm shakes its window at me, showing no real error in the output log. Anyone have success with this?

Comment: @BrianJordan thanks to you I've updated my answer, please try the new solution

Comment: On mac it's `/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm  \1 --line \2`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just operate `Tools > Create Commandline Launcher` in intellij or other jetbrains  IDE.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40516021/2499870 answer was almost perfect, although I wasn't getting the line correctly. Inverting the order worked. Putting first the line and then the file.

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea --line \2 \1
```

Answer (score -3):

Just go to intellij.
type in keys CMD + Shift + A
and type "Create commandline launcher"
Enter
And click Ok

You are good to go
Go to terminal and type idea . to open project in intellij