# WebStorm: open file at line number instantly

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Is it possible to open WebStorm at a file and line number instantly?

This takes about 5 seconds to detect a currently running instance, but **does** jump to file/line:

```
"/Users/x/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/WebStorm/ch-0/192.6817.13/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm" --line #{ARGV[1]} #{ARGV[0]}
```

The JetBrains Toolbox installed `sh` at `/usr/local/bin/webstorm` does **not** allow passing line numbers (but does open instantly):

```
open -a "/Users/x/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/WebStorm/ch-0/192.6817.13/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm" "$@"
```

I have tried:

- `webstorm $file:$line` (file does not exist)
- `webstorm --line $line $file` (`open` args error)
- `webstorm --args --line $line $file` (ignores both file and line, but focuses window)

It seems a recent Toolbox update has created this issue as `webstorm` used to work with line numbers.

Related:

- [Open file on IntelliJ from iTerm 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516020/open-file-on-intellij-from-iterm-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please vote for [TBX-3478](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-3478) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Any idea how long it will take to fix the issue Lena? Waiting for 5-10 seconds to jump to a line is unusable.